# Retrieving MYSQL Join values from PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysql, left-join

I have two or more tables which hold values under the same column name. Now when I join these two tables the column names stay the same. When retrieving these values in PHP ($row['name']) I encounter problems since the column 'name' is used twice.

Are there any possible means of separating these two columns inside the query?

```
  SELECT *
    FROM stories s
    JOIN authors a ON a.id = s.authorid
```

Table ***stories***
id, name, content, date

Table ***authors***
id, name, date

When i join these two i get one table with similar 'name' columns.

Is there anyway to separate the two tables so the author table has a prefix in front of it? E.g. authors_name /authors_*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, change your SQL this way :

```
SELECT 
  s.Id as StoryId, 
  s.Name as StoryName,
  a.Id as AuthorId, 
  a.Name as AthorName,
FROM stories s
JOIN authors a ON a.id = s.authorid
```

Then in php, use StoryId, StoryName, AuthorId and AthorName instead of Id or Name.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, this should do the trick, however I was hoping I could add a prefix which would automatically add something like authors_*

Comment: Unfortunatly it looks like there is no automatic prefixing. If this answer is ok, don't forget to 'accept' it :p

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is!

```
SELECT *, stories.name AS s_name, authors.name AS a_name
FROM stories s
JOIN authors a ON a.id = s.authorid
```

And there you have it. All fields plus two extra! ;)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate all your replies. I would individually add a thank you note to all since I am a newbie at SO.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you can't really do prefixing on a field level, but if you can call 2 queries, just use

```
SELECT s.*
FROM stories s
JOIN authors a ON a.id = s.authorid
```

The result set will only contain stories fields and you can use the fields as you normally would with php. Then just do the same again for authors.